# Item removed from Knockout observable array, but not from html table

Tags: knockout.js, footable

I have a plunk that demonstrates my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/PzBrcTX0Vnn01xWy4dk6

This is a table that has a list of "settings".  It uses Footable so the list can be sorted and other features of Footable.

Scenario 1: run, push the remove setting button for one or more rows.  Notice that the row is removed after the buttons is pushed.  This is the expected behavior.

Scenario 2: run, click on the setting column header and ensure that the column is sorted, push the remove button.  Notice that the row is not removed from the view.

If you put a break point in ApplicationSettings.js:

```
var removeItem = function (item) {
    items.remove(item);
};
```

You can see that in both scenarios the observable array is removing the items as expected, but in scenario 2 the view is not updated as expected.

Comment: The sort function creates a new array that is not bound to the view. If you need more help, you really need to reduce the amount of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue comes from the empty text nodes that surround each `<tr>` element. The `foreach` binding also tracks those text nodes. See https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/709 for a discussion about why it's not possible to just ignore them as a general rule. On the other hand, your custom binding can strip them out.

See how [knockout-sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable/blob/900e426bebc9f218dee567a2545cc46957f575ac/src/knockout-sortable.js#L90-L94) does this (for similar reasons):

```
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function(node) {
    if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    }
});
```

You need to make sure this is run before `foreach`. I modified your binding to do that: http://plnkr.co/edit/hS6Gb2xLfabSj9K8l03y?p=preview

Comment: I added the code from knockout-sortable, but that didn't fix the issues.  I tried the hack mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628050/ignore-whitespace-in-html.  Then I removed all of the spaces from the <tbody> so it's all on one row.  This actually fixed the problem.  If I push a single space between the <tbody> and the first <tr> it breaks again.  So, I either didn't implement the code from knockout-sortable correctly or the code is called after the foreach binding.  I'm guessing it's the later.  I'll see what I can do about that in the morning and report back...

Comment: I modified your binding to do it before `foreach`. See my edits above.

Comment: The code I posted didn't work for every case. I've updated it now (and the Plunker).

Comment: Wow!  What's a case that failed the previous version and how did you go about finding the failure?

Comment: I noticed a recent [Knockout-sortable issue](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable/issues/81) about a problem related to the code. My update is slightly different since I didn't use jQuery.