# Footable and Knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js, footable

I have a table that is bound using the Knockout.js ForEach.i have used footable for responsivity and more compatibility in tablet and mobile.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Service Date</th>
            <th data-hide="phone">Code</th>
            <th data-hide="phone">Start Date</th>


<tbody data-bind="foreach: myCollection">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:ServiceDate"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:Code"></td>
```

In the large screen i don't have problem,but when i re-size the page expand icon doesn't work i have this error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null"
i found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809746/how-to-refresh-footable-that-is-bound-with-knockout) but i couldn't solve my issue yet.

Comment: Try closing your tags =>  table, thead, tbody and tr

Comment: I think the answers and plunks from this question should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/20809746/2033294 and this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/20893516/2033294